# Phpmyadmin, duplicate one post line as thousand, million?

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Hi I need to make a database test, but I need currently between thousands and millions of posts(data), is it possible to have these automatically duplicated from one copy like 'Lorem Ipsum...'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://www.databasetestdata.com/ you can generate sample dta for your database in JSON format. Then create simple code to parse it and insert it into your database, then you can use it to test your database.